# basic joomla extension development confusion

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I want to develop a joomla 2.5 porfolio extension.
So I need something in the backend to enter a couple of details.
On my frontpage I want to have listed the six latest projects and there will be a page in the frontend where all projects are listed. 
I'm new to this whole joomla thing. At the moment I'm reading through the joomla docs and tutorials.

I'm a little bit confused because I'm not really sure which type of extension do I need.
Can all this be done with a single component or a module or do I have to mix both?
Because what I've understood so far a component can just be displayed as a independent page.
And a module has to be included in a page. Like {lastSixProjects}?

Can some please enlighten me a little bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a page with portofolio only, you may create a component without a module...

If you want to put your portofolio in eg.: articles pages, search page, in a sidebar etc (like a image slideshow plugin) you must create a module (with a component assigned to it)

Please read this: http://docs.joomla.org/Extension_types_%28general_definitions%29 .

I undestrand that you want to put your portofolio in your front page... in this chase you MUST create a module.

Little explanation:

A module is an extension (similary to boxes, or widgets) that are arranged arround a component (in this chase com_content - on your FrontPage). Eg: Ads Module, Search Box Module etc.

A component is a super complex extension (similary to mini applications). It has an administration part and front-end part. All Joomla! pages loads a component. Eg: Content component, Search component etc.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You want a component. Please read this: http://docs.joomla.org/Extension_types_%28general_definitions%29

Comment: ok got it
but for my "last six projects" box on the frontpage I need an extra module?

Answer (score 0):

Agree on 2 previous answers, you need a component with at least one table to store your projects. Then you need to link to a menu a view of the elements on a table. You should be able to make it work in 15 minutes with this component creator for Joomla http://www.component-creator.com/